# PHP image resize doesn't work as I want

Tags: javascript, php, image, resize

I've a problem during simple basic PHP image resize.

I pass my image in POST using an AJAX call..

This is my PHP code:

```
//resize original image
            switch ($type) {
                case "desktop":
                    $width = 1920;
                    $height = 1080;
                break;

                case "mobile":
                        $width = 640;
                        $height = 1080;
                    break;
            }

                print_r("start resize");
                print_r('<br>');

                $size = getimagesize($url);
                $img_origX = imagesx($img_orig);
                $img_origY = imagesy($img_orig);
                //height (Auto calculate)
                //$height = round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);
                $img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
                imagecopyresampled($img, $img_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $img_origX, $img_origY);

                // Output
                header('Content-type: image/jpg');
                imagejpeg($img , "thumbnail.jpg");

                $imageData = fopen("thumbnail.jpg", "r");

                print_r("resize ok");
                print_r('<br>');
```

The problem is that in network I never receive "resize ok", something goes wrong..

Is it correct the sequence?

Comment: use error_log to dump information to the error log. This won't work

Comment: Your image got successfully resized or not?

Answer (score 0):

remove the `print_r`, when you're outputting image it should have only the data of the image.
If you want only to output the image you need only one params in `imagejpeg`: `imagejpeg($img);`
And Why you open a file `$imageData = fopen("thumbnail.jpg", "r");`? this is not necessary for outputting an image